# Prevent Logout on page refresh in React+Redux App

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, jwt

Logging out on page refresh in React + Redux Application, but if I store token in localstorage, then it works fine, but i don't want to store token in localstorage. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: keep the token in Cookies. And pick the token directly from cookies wherever you are making api call or handling the logic of redirection to logged in state app.

Comment: @simbathesailor, but cookies will be accessible in react ?

Comment: Yup cookies have nothing to do with reactjs. Its browser feature.

Comment: You can accept cookies with `document.cookie`. `document` is a global object and is accessible from `javascript`, so if from `reactjs`.